# SELECT Customers today delivery lines postgres SQL command

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose order_date[ consider today date as]='2020-11-12 08:42:40'

I want to find the deliveries that have done today.

```
SELECT * FROM trip_delivery_sales_lines ts
WHERE  ts.order_date='CURRENT_DATE'
```

but not able to fetch details

Comment: Don't quote `CURRENT_DATE`.

Comment: Without quotes.,it also not showing any details

Comment: use `where date(ts.order_date)=current_date`

Comment: What is the field type for `order_date`? Are there any order_dates that match today(`CURRENT_DATE`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ts.order_date` is a `timestamp` field. When you are comparing the `current_date` using `=` operator, it is comparing with `todays date 00:00:00` which is likely not possible to have any result always. So either you have to convert both sides into `date` or use `>=` operator for your problem.

Try any of below for current date:

```
SELECT * FROM trip_delivery_sales_lines ts
WHERE  date(ts.order_date)=CURRENT_DATE
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM trip_delivery_sales_lines ts
WHERE  ts.order_date>=CURRENT_DATE
```

Note: 2 option is only for `current_date` comparison.